# Using Variable inside pregmatch in js

Tags: javascript, preg-match

I have the following orginal code of preg match

```
for(var i = 0;i<5;i++)
{ 
patt1 = /Colour1\/(\d+)"/; 
var ab=(data.match(patt1)[1]); 
alert(ab);
}
```

I am wondering if i can use the variable i instead of 1(for 5 loops),like below example.I can use the value **i** outside but not inside pregmatch.

```
 for(var i = 0;i<5;i++)
{<br>
patt1 = /Colour"+i+"\/(\d+)"/; 
var ab=(data.match(patt1)[1]); 
alert(ab);
}
```

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var patt1 = new RegExp('Colour' + i + '/(\\d+)"'),
        ab = (data.match(patt1) || [])[1]; 
    alert(ab);
}
```

Remember to double escape your slashes!

---

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/q2C55/

Comment: You forgot to double up on the backslashes

Comment: I don't think you need to escape slashes if you're not using `/regex/` notation.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var ab = data.match('Colour'+i+'/(\\d+)"')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
patt1 = new RegExp("Colour"+i+"/(\\d+)\"");
```

but you could also skip the loop

```
patt1 = new RegExp("Colour[0-4]/(\\d+)\"");
```

Comment: @JustinBiaber: You're welcome. I just updated it to require the closing `"` in the regex. If that's not needed, remove the `\"`.